# How to manage C++ principles with C compatible libraries and APIs

Tags: c++, c

I'm new with C++ and currently I'm working on some project and want to use C++ instead of C.

The first problem that I came across is that for example in OpenSSL there are functions which accept `char*` as arguments.

In C++ it's not a good idea to use `char*`. I've read that some people recommend `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead.

But for example `BIO_read` (which writes data into `char*`) function in OpenSSL accepts `char*`. `std::string` has function `c_str()` but it returns `const char*`. I know I can cast `const` using `const_cast` but it's not a good idea because it's not the way string should be changed.

What is the "C++ solution" to this problem? I want to use both RAII and OOP principles. The only solution I could think of is to create a class which would accept memory size as argument in constructor and have something like this `char* _buf = new char[size]` and deallocate memory in destructor. Is it the best solution to this situation?

Or where should I put my data received from socket using `recv` when I don't know the size? In C I would have allocated memory using `malloc` and wrote it there. But how can I do this in "C++ style"? Create class that I mentioned above and use it instead of `malloc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string` also has `.data()` which you should use for this task (at least in modern C++ where string data is guaranteed to be contiguous).

Other than that, yes you may have to make some trade-offs from C++ best-practices when working with C APIs. This is particularly noticeable with callbacks, to which you cannot pass capturing lambdas or pointers-to-member-functions without some amount of ugly machinery.

Some C libraries are complemented by C++ wrappers, written either by the original library's author or by a third party (e.g. MySQL++, curlpp) — that means the ugly machinery has been done for you, and you don't have to worry about it.

Your `_buf` solution isn't terrible, but a `std::vector<char>` then may be better or a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` (though, again, consider that `std::string` may well be suitable for your needs after all).

For `recv`, that is a different matter, and it's not one that really relates to C++ design principles. You *already* need to consider that you do not know how many bytes are readable, so you *already* need to read repeatedly into a little buffer and handle the data as it comes. So you can keep using your nice automatic-storage `char buf[1024]` for this — there was never a need for `malloc` there, and there still isn't one now.

Comment: So creating external class which I described is acceptable to use it instead of `malloc`?

Comment: You don't need to. Just have `static constexpr size_t bufSize = 1024; char buf[bufSize] = {};` then use `buf` and `bufSize`. And, once more, if you _do_ need dynamic allocation, you _can_ use `std::string` or `std::vector`. I believe you're overthinking it.

Comment: In other words, `std::string` or `std::vector` _is already the class you describe_!

Comment: But there are situations where I need to dynamically allocate memory, for example in winapi make `GetTokenInformation`  function fail for the first time to retrieve the size of buffer. what is the best practice there?

Comment: @Ojs I've already said a few times :( Is there something unclear about the suggestion to use `std::string` or `std::vector`?