# C++: pass pointer of a pointer to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, openssl

I'm new with C++ and trying to integrate `Openssl` to my project. Some of the functions here for example `i2d_RSAPublicKey` receives `unsigned char**` as second argument and stores some data in it. I've had similar question asked here:

[How to manage C++ principles with C compatible libraries and APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277703/how-to-manage-c-principles-with-c-compatible-libraries-and-apis)

But since using `std::string` and `std::vector` doesn't come handy here, I've decided to ask another question.

Since `std::string::c_str()` returns `const` row pointer and `std::vector::data()` returns just row pointer, they are not compatible with this function. Plus I don't think manipulating row pointer to store data in `std::string` or `std::vector` is a good idea.

So my question is what data type should I use to not violate `RAII` standard and pass pointer of a pointer to a function which will store some data in it?

Comment: You would be *amazed* how tidy you can make your openssl code with a few judicious template specializations of `std::default_delete` and `std::unique_ptr` That said, the function you're asking about uses a basic raw pointer to communicate how deep `i2d_RSAPublicKey` dove into the data blob you're writing. While the data blob may be RAII managed, that specific pointer doesn't need to be. In short, consider what the argument is doing before worrying about wrapping it up in an unneeded RAII construct.

Comment: I don't think `std::unique_ptr` could be used with `openssl` very often. Even in my case I can't pass pointer of a pointer to a function using `std::unique_tr`

Comment: I beg to differ. wrapping all those dynamic management constructs under the watchful guise of `std::unique_ptr` means you never have to worry about  else-case proliferated cleanup. Ex: `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup` and `EVP_MD_CYX_destroy`. It happens as soon as the `std::unique_ptr<EVP_MD_CTX>` leaves scope, be it because of an exception, function return, whatever. All it takes is a proper deleter to make it happen. Regardless, in your case, are you talking about the specific case where `unsigned char *p = NULL;` then passing `&p` and letting the lib `OPENSSL_malloc` memory for the DER-encoding?

Comment: yes, and how can `std::unique_ptr` be used there?

Comment: In that specific case you can't (easily). You'd have to know the size of the DER (at least minimally) to  write direct to buffer managed by a vector. If you're using the openssl api to allocate that specific buffer for you there is no smart wrapper to contain it in the standard lib. I've never had to deal with it because the math of the DER size for a given pkey (either public or private+public) is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Even if I knew the size, how can I pass `char **` to a function using `std::unique_ptr` isn't `std::unique_ptr::get` retrieving pointer of row data(not reference)? Is it correct way to store data in it?

Comment: I'll throw together an example, it will take a few minutes. Sry. RL work is constantly interrupting my SO hobby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` can accept a custom deleter, which can let it manage OpenSSL-allocated memory.  Exactly what function it needs to call to clean things up depends on what function allocated it, but for the example of `i2d_RSAPublicKey` you used in your example, it needs to wrap `OPENSSL_free`:

```
struct OpenSSLFree
{
    void operator()(void* ptr)
    {
        OPENSSL_free(ptr);
    }
};

template <typename T>
using OpenSSLPointer = std::unique_ptr<T, OpenSSLFree>;

OpenSSLPointer<unsigned char> EncodeRSAPublicKey(RSA* key)
{
    unsigned char* out = nullptr;
    int status = i2d_RSAPublicKey(key, &out);
    if (status < 0) {
        // handle error
    }
    return OpenSSLPointer<unsigned char>{out};
}
```

The buffer containing the encoded key will then be cleaned up in an exception-safe manner.

---

You could also use `std::vector<unsigned char>` in this case.  You'll have to call `i2d_RSAPublicKey` twice: once to get the required buffer size and again to actually encode the data:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> EncodeRSAPublicKey(RSA* key)
{
    int len = i2d_RSAPublicKey(key, nullptr);
    if (len < 0) {
        // handle error
    }

    std::vector<unsigned char> outVec(len);
    unsigned char* outPtr = outVec.data();
    len = i2d_RSAPublicKey(key, &outPtr);
    if (len < 0) {
        // handle error
    }

    return outVec;
}
```

This is likely a cleaner interface, but it won't work everywhere.  The `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter approach is widely applicable, but again, the function to be called by the deleter will depend on how the memory is allocated.

Comment: Are you sure retrieving pointer behind `std::vector` with `.data()` and manipulating it to store some data in `std::vector` is a good idea?

Comment: @Ojs That is why the `data` method exists.

Comment: But since it doesn't return reference of a pointer, what if some string literal is assigned to pointer? It would not change the content of vector right?

Comment: `i2d_RSAPublicKey` writes to `**out` and modifies `*out`.  That means in this example, that it writes to the buffer pointed to by `outPtr` (which is the buffer managed by `outVec`) and modifies the pointer `outPtr` to point to the element after the end of `outVec`.  After the call `outPtr == &*outVec.end()` will hold true.

Comment: then why does i2d_RSAPublicKey needs you to pass char**? could not it do the same if it accepted char*?

Comment: @ZhaniBaramidze Because it wants to modify the pointer you pass to it to point past the end of the data it writes.  Here, I tried to draw a [before](https://pastebin.com/1eeCK7gJ) and [after](https://pastebin.com/CPKSTTTT) diagram.